# She {looks/is looking/looking} worried about something?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

> She ____ worried about something?

options:

> a) looks
> b) is looking
> c) looking

My approach:

"She **looks** worried about something?" because "is looking" will not be the answer because "is ((look) v1+ing +v2)" is not any form and "looking" doesn't fit in the solution.

So, I put "looks".

Answer (score 2):

- *she looks* is okay.

  This is correct because *looks* is singular, and the subject *she* is singular. So it is correct to say:

  > She looks worried about something. [correct]
- *she is looking* is okay, but in spoken English the contraction *she's looking* would be more common.

  If you wish to use looking as part of a verb phrase you need another verb, such as: *She is looking*, *I am looking*, or *They are looking*.

  > She is looking worried about something. [correct]

  And so you are correct to say the following doesn’t fit:

  > She looking worried about something. [incorrect]
- Look is plural, so you need a plural subject. So it would be correct to say

  > They look worried about something. [correct]

  But incorrect to use it when the subject is singular:

  > She look worried about something. [incorrect]

Comment: Is the structure of the sentence right when we choose "is looking" ?How can i judge more accurately?

Comment: I'll edit my answer and add some more detail. The choice of verb is to do with number (she is singular). But for now, just know that the sentence 'She looks worried about something' is correct.

Comment: Here look acts as a linking verb so how is looking can be used?

Answer (score 0):

First, you're right that *she looks worried* is grammatical.

Secondly, you're right that *she looking worried* is not grammatical in any standard English, though there are some dialects that allow it.

But your analysis of *she is looking worried* is wrong, because *worried* is not a verb here but an adjective, and it can be a complement of *look* just like other adjectives (as it is, in fact, in *she looks worried*).

For a more permanent appearance, the "simple present" would be better:

> She looks aristocratic.

but for a (usually) temporary appearance, the "present continuous" is more normal:

> She is looking worried about something.

Having said that, *she looks worried about something* is not wrong, and there are contexts where it would be perfectly natural. But *she is looking worried about something* is more generally likely.